# What factors limit hard drive capacity?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

Can anybody explain me what factors limit hard drive capacity? I mean, why don't we have HDD with 1000 terabytes of capacity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can do your own research on the subject, but [it all started here...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USJGui9yIuA)

Comment: The largest commercially available SSD drive on 21/10/2015 is this one, http://petapixel.com/2015/08/15/samsung-16tb-ssd-is-the-worlds-largest-hard-drive/, 16TB, with an expected price of at least 7000 US$.

Comment: SSD != hard drive.

Comment: Tho at the moment, SSDs have greater potential data density than a HDD.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I totally agree, Seagate is talking about a 60 Terabyte SSD, that is definitely where the future is headed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Areal density

The bit values of 1 and 0 are not stored directly on the magnetic substrate.  Instead the magnetic domains are polarized to generate flux reversals.  A flux reversal indicates a change in bit state, whereas no flux reversal indicates the same bit state.  The initial bit state is always presumed to be 0.

The magnetic substrate has a minimal area required for a magnetic domain that can generate a flux reversal which will generate a required current in a read head.  The areal density is the inverse of this area for a magnetic domain.  The maximum areal density is related to the maximum recorded bit density.

## 2. HDD size

When disk drives were in floor-standing cabinets, the easy method of increasing capacity was to increase the number of platters.  The largest disk pack (that I know of) in mass production had 20 data surfaces on twelve 14" platters.
But the modern trend is toward small size and low power (e.g. just one or two platters).

## 3. Positioner accuracy

The typical read/write head assembly traces an arc across the platter surface instead of the ideal radius.  The length of this arc has to be kept short to minimize the tangential error.  But for a given arc, the accuracy of the electromechanics at a given price point can only resolve N tracks per inch.

Answer (score 3):

***Physics***. Or more precisely the ability to store ever smaller magnetic domains into smaller cases. While in theory you could increase the size of platters and the number of platters practically that would increase seek times (since your heads don't move independantly, and would need to seek a larger area).

There's a few technologies that have attempted to increase density - [perpendicular recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular_recording), which rearranged how magnetic domains were laid out, [SMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording), which overlaps tracks and [HAMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording), which uses smaller domains made possible by demagnatising areas temporarily with a laser.

They also fill some drives with [helium](http://www.pcworld.com/article/262274/helium_filled_wd_drives_promise_huge_boost_in_capacity.html) for better internal cooling, and less resistance.

At the end of the day though you're going to hit a wall.

There's also a matter of *economics*. There's almost no one who needs a single petabyte disk, no matter how large, when a large array of redundant inexpensive hard drives would do that and a fair bit less cost, better speeds (since you can split up the data transfer over multiple interfaces, and manage everything on an enclosure), and better reliability (oops. I just dropped a 1pb drive out of a window and all my data is gone).

In short. It dosen't make sense to.

Eventually you could get *better* densities and speeds from NAND (simply by packing in more, bigger chips where there would be air and mechanical bits) in a normal HDD, but there's a different set of tradeoffs - process size vs reliability vs yield, the need to control more chips makes the controllers more complex and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it comes down to component size/density/cost limitations.

Larger capacity drives require higher density components, which in turn require more manufacturing input, which in turn costs more.

Think of SSD drives as a bunch of connected thumb drive chips, current technology can only get them down to a certain size to fit into a box that will fit a harddrive enclosure. (although some are built straight into motherboards or cards). As the size can be made smaller, manufacturers can put more in. Thats the most basic way of looking at it.

Unlike HDD, instead of a magnetic coating on top of platters, the data is stored on memory chips that retain the data. These memory chips are different from those in a thumb drive, faster, more reliable, and more expensive to make. But in very basic terms they work the same way.